# not act like a girl and to be so beautiful

Tags: sentence-structure

this is the text:

> “Sit still,” Ma says as she reaches down to stop my leg midswing, but
>   I end up kicking her hand. Ma gives me a stern look and a swift slap
>   on my leg. “Don’t you ever sit still? You are five years old. You are
>   the most troublesome child. Why can’t you be like your sisters? How
>   will you ever grow up to be a proper young lady?” Ma sighs. Of course
>   I have heard all this before. It must be hard for her to have a
>   daughter **who does not act like a girl, to be so beautiful** and have a
>   daughter like me. Chat conversation end

It says who **does not act like a girl, to be so beautiful**

Is it a paradox to not act like a girl and to be so beautiful ?

Comment: The subject of *to be so beautiful...* is Ma, not the narrator.

Comment: Where did this come from?? Please cite your source.

Comment: Its from a book First they killed my father .https://www.amazon.com/First-They-Killed-Father-Remembers/dp/B0017ODVCW              why shall I cite my source

Answer (score 1):

The bolded phrases in your sentence are parallel complements of "hard (for her)".

> It must be hard for her to have a daughter who does not act like a
>   girl.
>
> It must be hard for her to be so beautiful and have a daughter like
>   me.

Compare:

> It must be **hard** for the injured star player **to sit the bench** during
>   the championship game, **to watch** his team losing.